# Как упаковать исходный код в jar-файл

Tags: java, netbeans

В задании просят предоставить истолняемый jar-файл вида <имя проекта>.jar и исходники в виде <имя проекта>-src.jar. Исполняемый файл я получил, а как сделать исходник? Пользуюсь NetBeans 6.9.1. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А `jar cf <имя-проекта>-src.jar *.java` не помогает?

Comment: О, спасибо! Не знал, что это делается из командной строки)

Answer (score 1):

В файле `biuld.xml` в последней строке внутри `<project>` можно добавить код

```
<target name="-post-jar" description="bundle sources and javadoc in a jar" depends="javadoc">
    <jar compress="${jar.compress}" basedir="${src.dir}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${application.title}-sources.jar"/>
    <jar compress="${jar.compress}" basedir="${dist.javadoc.dir}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${application.title}-javadoc.jar"/>
</target>
```

тут создается и исходники и javadoc. только нужно указать название программы `Application Name` в `<Проект>/Properties/Application/Title`

Answer (score 0):

jar - это обычный zip =) залезь в папку с сорцами, запакуй из раром и переименуй расширение

Comment: иполняемый jar так не соберёшь

Comment: сорци - это не исполняемые файлы